# The correct way to return the only element from a set

Tags: java, collections, set

I have the following kind of situation:

```
Set<Element> set = getSetFromSomewhere();
if (set.size() == 1) {
    // return the only element
} else {
    throw new Exception("Something is not right..");
}
```

Assuming I cannot change the return type of `getSetFromSomewhere()`, is there a better or more correct way to return the only element in the set than

- Iterating over the set and returning immediately
- Creating a list from the set and calling `.get(0)`

Comment: You can invoke toArray() method and then access the 0th index. But, i think this is quite similar with "creating a list"

Comment: Good question... no good answers

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use an `Iterator` to both obtain the only element as well as verify that the collection only contains one element (thereby avoiding the `size()` call and the unnecessary list creation):

```
Iterator<Element> iterator = set.iterator();

if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Collection is empty");
}

Element element = iterator.next();

if (iterator.hasNext()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Collection contains more than one item");
}

return element;
```

You would typically wrap this up in its own method:

```
public static <E> E getOnlyElement(Iterable<E> iterable) {
    Iterator<E> iterator = iterable.iterator();

    // The code I mentioned above...
}
```

Note that this implementation is already part of Google's [Guava libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (which I *highly* recommend, even if you don't use it for this particular code). More specifically, the method belongs to the [`Iterables` class](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html):

```
Element element = Iterables.getOnlyElement(set);
```

If you're curious about how it is implemented, you can look at the [`Iterators` class source code](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.java) (the methods in `Iterables` often call methods in `Iterators`):

```
  /**
   * Returns the single element contained in {@code iterator}.
   *
   * @throws NoSuchElementException if the iterator is empty
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the iterator contains multiple
   *     elements.  The state of the iterator is unspecified.
   */
  public static <T> T getOnlyElement(Iterator<T> iterator) {
    T first = iterator.next();
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
      return first;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("expected one element but was: <" + first);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 && iterator.hasNext(); i++) {
      sb.append(", " + iterator.next());
    }
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
      sb.append(", ...");
    }
    sb.append('>');

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(sb.toString());
  }
```

Comment: You'll specifically want `Iterables.getOnlyElement()` in your case. It is one of the most popular methods in Guava.  I strongly recommend it. :-)

Comment: @Kevin: I guess my answer wasn't clear enough. I *did* recommend `Iterables.getOnlyElement`, but I illustrated its behavior via `Iterators.getOnlyElement` (because `Iterables` calls `Iterators`).

Answer (score 24):

The best *general* solution (where you don't know the actual set class) is:

```
Element first = set.iterator().next();
```

If the set class is known to be a `SortedSet` (e.g. a `TreeSet` or `ConcurrentSkipListSet`), then a better solution is:

```
Element first = ((SortedSet) set).first();
```

In both cases, an exception will be thrown if the set is empty; check the javadocs.   The exception can be avoided using `Collection.isEmpty()`.

---

The first solution is `O(1)` in time and space for a `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet`, but typically worse for other kinds of set.

The second one is `O(logN)` in time , and uses no space for `TreeSet` or `ConcurrentSkipListSet`.

The approach of creating a list from the set contents and then calling `List.get(0)` gives a poor solution since the first step is an `O(N)` operation, both in time and space.

---

I failed to notice that `N` is actually `1`.  But even so, creating an iterator is likely to be less expensive than creating a temporary list.

Answer (score 10):

You could grab the iterator:

```
Element firstEl = set.iterator().next();
```

Comment: This is what I usually do, but I wrap it in a method with an assertion `assert set.size() == 1` thrown in.

Answer (score 8):

In Java 8, we can do like below:

```
set.stream().findFirst().get()
```

But, remember to check the size of set before as `Optional.get()` throws `NoSuchElementException`